# Failed Parsing XML File into ASP MVC

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

i have a XML file that should be loaded on ASP MVC, i got the data from my Service, but failed parsing, idk why but the data can't go through List. Here my code

**XML File**

```
<ArrayOfNews xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DIESWCF" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<News>
<CompID>70101</CompID>
<Descriptions>as the winner of awards</Descriptions>
<ImgPath>Company/UI.png</ImgPath>
<Title>University of Indonesia Animate Version</Title>
</News>
</ArrayOfNews>
```

**Models**

```
    public class News
    {
        private int _compid;
        private string _title, _desc, _img;
        public int CompID
        {
            get { return _compid; }
            set { _compid = value; }
        }
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { _title = value; }
        }
        public string Descriptions
        {
            get { return _desc; }
            set { _desc = value; }
        }
        public string ImgPath
        {
            get { return _img; }
            set { _img = value; }
        }
    }
```

**Process**

```
public List<News> GetViewNews()
    {

      List<News> newslist = new List<News>();
      XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
      doc.Load(SU.URLService() + "ViewNews");
      foreach (XmlNode feed in doc.SelectNodes("/ArrayOfNews/News"))
       {
          newslist.Add(new News
           {                       
             CompID = Convert.ToInt32(feed["CompID"].InnerText),
             Title = feed["Title"].InnerText,
             ImgPath = feed["http://localhost:54654/" + "ImgPath"].InnerText,
             Descriptions = feed["Descriptions"].InnerText
            });
       }           
       return newslist;
   }
```

When i try to breakpoints on `doc` line, i got the data but however the return always gives 0 count. Any Idea?

Comment: @CodeNotFound can you give me an example?

Comment: Yes it works perfectly. I got the data but failed on XmlNode line

Comment: Side note: please re-read [MCVE] guidance to avoid posting large amount of code most of which is not related to the problem. I.e. if you can't select a node from Xml there is no point in showing some class unless your question is actually about deserializing XML to class.